# ActionListener handling from keyboard

Tags: java

When confirm dialog show up and I click "Cancel" by mouse button it's work fine, program still running. But if i choose "Cancel" navigate from keyboard and push "Enter" when "Cancel" is focused my program shut down.

```
exitItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            int action = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(MainFrame.this, "Do you really want to exit?", "Confirm Exit", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);

            if (action == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION){
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: "Enter" means execute the "OK" functionality, try "Space-bar" to activate the selected button (assuming the question is why it is not *doing* the cancel...)

Comment: Omg, that is so obvious. Thx.